# Apache error to start

Tags: networking, systemd, apache-httpd, kali-linux

I'm trying to start `apache2` and it gives me this error:

```
root@kali:~# service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status apache2.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details
```

The status shows:

```
# systemctl  status apache2.service
```

[image]

The journal log shows:

```
# journalctl  -xe .....
```

[image]

Comment: What's already listening on port 80? Use netstat or lsof to find that out

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: root@kali:~# netstat -plnt | grep ':80'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22620/python3

Comment: Did you see that part about the Apache error log?

Comment: Switch your screenshots to text copy-paste and you will get my reopen vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some other process already listening on port 80.  Based on your netstat command output from your comment above -

```
root@kali:~# netstat -plnt | grep ':80' tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 22620/python3
```

It looks like some python script is acting as a webserver.  Re-run the command to get the current process id (the 222620 in this example) and then run `cat /proc/NUMBER/commandline` on it to see what script was actually called, or look for it in the output of `top`, `ps` and similar tools.

Comment: i kill the proccess the work on port 80 and apache2 going to start +1 thankx

Comment: So who is down voting and why?